# How to filter LiveData List based on LiveData Map?

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have to asynchronous operations. In the viewmodel, the two need to work together for the UI. How can I filter the LiveData list based on the keys in de LiveData map? (Object id's in list correspond to Map keys)

```
@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
private val _allJourneys = MutableLiveData<List<Journey>>()
val allJourneys: LiveData<List<Journey>> get() = _allJourneys

@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.PRIVATE)
private val _enrolledMap = MutableLiveData<Map<String, String>>()
val enrolledMap: LiveData<Map<String, String>> get() = _enrolledMap

fun getEnrolled() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        progressRepository.getEnrolledJourneysMapOfUser().observeForever {
            Timber.d("Map values: $it")
            _enrolledMap.value = it
        }
    }

}

fun getJourneys() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        journeysRepository.getAll().observeForever { it ->
            _allJourneys.value = it.filter {
               // enrolledMap.containsKey(it.id) ??? Nullpointer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to filter Journeys based on enrolledMap keys, correct? How about using [transformations](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7)? This way you can move the observer to UI and just pass the LiveData reference. MediatorLiveData can be useful as well

Comment: @Stachu Thanks for the comment. At what point in the architecture do I filter the journeys based on the map? I am using MVVM and Cloud Firestore.

Comment: do `journeysRepository.getAll()` and `progressRepository.getEnrolledJourneysMapOfUser()` return LiveData?

Comment: @Stachu LiveData<out List<Journey>>, it does.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this (based on the MediatorLiveData example from [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7))

```kotlin
    val allJourneys: LiveData<List<Journey>> = journeysRepository.getAll()
    val enrolledMap: LiveData<Map<String, String>> = progressRepository.getEnrolledJourneysMapOfUser()

    private val _filteredJourneys = MediatorLiveData<List<Journey>>()
    private val filteredJourneys: LiveData<List<Journey>> = _filteredJourneys

    init {
        _filteredJourneys.addSource(allJourneys) {
            combineLatestData(allJourneys,enrolledMap)
        }
        _filteredJourneys.addSource(enrolledMap) {
            combineLatestData(allJourneys,enrolledMap)
        }
    }

    private fun combineLatestData(
        journeysLD: LiveData<List<Journey>>,
        enrolledLD: LiveData<Map<String, String>>
    ): List<Journey>? {
        val j = journeysLD.value
        val e = enrolledLD.value
        val result = listOf<Journey>()
        if (j == null || e == null) {
            return result // TODO filter j by e
        }
        return null
    }
```

the changes in the `allJourney` and `enrolledMap` LiveData should trigger the `combineLatestData`

Comment: On the top val: Suspend function 'getAll' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Comment: `getAll` is suspended because of Cloud Firestore? For Room I never use suspend with LiveData

Comment: Yes, depending if local db is empty, then remote data is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

`observeForever` is wrong approach inside a ViewModel. Each time `get__` is called, a new subscription would be made, and you will get multiple subscriptions and possibly memory leaks inside your ViewModel until the garbage collector clears the stuck subscriptions.

Instead, as you are using LiveData, you should just use the return values and keep them as fields.

```
val allJourneys: LiveData<List<Journey>> get() = journeysRepository.getAll()
    
val enrolledMap: LiveData<Map<String, String>> get() = progressRepository.getEnrolledJourneysMapOfUser()

//fun getEnrolled() {
//    viewModelScope.launch {
//        .observeForever {
//            Timber.d("Map values: $it")
//            _enrolledMap.value = it
//        }
//    }
//
//}

//fun getJourneys() {
//    viewModelScope.launch {
//        .observeForever { it ->
//            _allJourneys.value = it.filter {
//               // enrolledMap.containsKey(it.id) ??? Nullpointer
//            }
//        }
//    }
//}
```

As LiveData from a Repository that comes from a DAO will already handle background data fetch.

If this is done manually with suspending functions in the Repository, then you can use `switchMap` + `liveData { emitSource` - but in this case, it does not seem necessary.

Comment: If I keep them as fields I get the error: "Suspend function 'getAll' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"